# CNN Overfitting

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I have a siamese CNN that is performing very well (96% accuracy, 0.08 loss) on training data but poorly (70% accuracy, 0.1 loss) on testing data.

The architecture is below:

```
input_main = Input(shape=input_shape, dtype='float32')
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu',
            kernel_regularizer=l2(0.005))(input_main)
x = Conv2D(16, (5, 5), activation='relu',
            kernel_regularizer=l2(0.005))(x)
x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(5, 5))(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)

x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu',
            kernel_regularizer=l2(0.0005))(x)
x = Conv2D(32, (7, 7), activation='relu',
            kernel_regularizer=l2(0.005))(x)
x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3))(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)

x = Flatten()(x)
#x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = Dense(16, activation='relu',
            kernel_regularizer=l2(0.005))(x)

model = Model(inputs=input_main, outputs=x)
```

Two of these are then combined to make a siamese architecture, and the difference between the vectors from the final layer informs the result. I have experimented with dropout and regularization, and neither has been able to solve the problem (these parameters are the ones I am testing at time of posting)

I have also tried simplifying the architecture to fewer conv layers, and this has not solved the problem.

The data is 256x128x1 images, sent through the network in pairs with binary labels based on whether they are the same or not. I also use data augmentation, with some small rotations and translations.

Can anyone suggest anything else to try to solve this overfitting problem?

Comment: have you tired batchnormalization

Comment: @Primusa Not yet, will try it